# Populate multible tables one form MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making a program for a camping. Customers can make a reservation at the website and the receptionist can accept them and add more information to the customer when they arrive (like number from passport).

My reservation table looks like this:

```
[ID]         INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[StartDatum] DATE         NULL,
[EindDatum]  DATE         NULL,
[Plaats]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Status]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[KlantID]    INT          NULL,
CONSTRAINT [FK_Reserveringen_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([KlantID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Klants] ([Id])
```

And my Customer table looks like this:

```
[Id]                INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Voornaam]          VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Achternaam]        VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Adres]             VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Postcode]          VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Plaats]            VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Telefoon]          INT          NOT NULL,
[Geboortedatum]     INT          NULL,
[Documentnr]        INT          NULL,
[Verificatiemiddel] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Emailadres]        VARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

I have a made a model for the customer table and reservations table.

This is how my view looks like to make the reservation on the website

```
 @model Camping.Domain.Entities.Reservering

 <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center"><h4>RSVP</h4></div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("KlantToevoegen", "Klant", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "mulipart/formdata" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Voornaam:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Voornaam, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Achternaam:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Achternaam, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Emailadres:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Emailadres, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Telefoonnummer:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Telefoonnnummer, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Datum aankomst:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartDatum, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Datum vertrek:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EindDatum, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Plaats:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Plaats, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Klant toevoegen" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

for this view I made a model. Which is:

```
 namespace Camping.Domain.Entities
   {
    public class Reservering
    {
        public string Voornaam { get; set; }
        public string Achternaam { get; set; }

        public int Telefoonnnummer { get; set; }
        public string Emailadres { get; set; }

        public string Plaats { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartDatum { get; set; }

        public DateTime EindDatum { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

And the controller class:

```
using Camping.Domain.Abstract;
using Camping.Domain.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Camping.WebUII.Controllers
{
    public class ReserveringController : Controller
    {
        private IRepository repository;

        public ReserveringController(IRepository iRepository)
        {
            this.repository = iRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult ReserveringAanmaken()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(Reservering model)
        {
            var klant = new Klant
            {
                Voornaam = model.Voornaam,
                Achternaam = model.Achternaam,
                Emailadres = model.Emailadres,
                Telefoon = model.Telefoonnnummer
            };

            var reservering = new Reserveringen
            {
                StartDatum = model.StartDatum,
                EindDatum = model.EindDatum,
                Plaats = model.Plaats
            };

            repository.KlantToevoegen(klant);
            repository.ReserveringToevoegen(reservering);

            return View();

        }
    }
}
```

This solution ain't working and for some reason it doesn't feel right what I am doing. Can anyone point me in the right direction? For more information. Feel free to ask :)

When I add the date via the view. I only fills up the Customer table and not the reservations table.

Comment: How it is not working, exactly?

Comment: I get an error: An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

inner exceptions? I can't seem to find them.

But I am on the right track do you think?

Comment: Run it with debugger, wait for the exception to happen. You will be able to see the exception details, among them there will be an `InnerException` property. There you will find a more helpful description of what happened.

Comment: Found out why I got the exception and fixed it, but the second table is not filled. So it fills up the Customer table, but not the Reservations table.

Comment: I think , Improper thing in your code is not using DB transaction.Also you would have detected the problem earlier had you done that

Answer (score 0):

you're passing a string from the view to the controller not a datetime